# How to find $\int \frac{\cos5x + 5\cos3x +10\cos x }{\cos6x+ 6\cos4x + 15\cos2x +10}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a integral which seems difficult to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Find 
$$\int \frac{\cos5x + 5\cos3x +10\cos x }{\cos6x+ 6\cos4x + 15\cos2x +10}\mathrm  dx$$

Also I wound like to know your thought process to solve integrals like these.

Comment: Express everything with $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$. Then put $t=tg(\frac{x}{2})$.

Comment: There might be a clever way with trig identities. But the only insight that immediately springs to mind is to replace $\cos nx$ with $\frac 12(e^{inx} + e^{-inx})$, then make the sub $u = e^{ix}$ and hope to god the algebra (factorisation of the denominator, partial fractions) is simple later on.

Comment: D'Moivers theorem can be used to find $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$ in terms of $\cos $ and $\sin $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand the cosines of multiple angles as functions of $\cos(x)$, you should arrive to $$\cos5x + 5\cos3x +10\cos x=16 \cos ^5 x$$ $$\cos6x+ 6\cos4x + 15\cos2x +10=32 \cos ^6 x$$ which means that $$\int \frac{\cos5x + 5\cos3x +10\cos x }{\cos6x+ 6\cos4x + 15\cos2x +10} \mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\sec x ~\mathrm dx$$ Now, use Weierstrass substitution.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Very neat. Could you just "see" that the powers of cosines would simplify like that or did you take a "leap of faith" and actually do the expansion?

Comment: The only thing I "saw" is that only odd angles appear in numerator and even angles appear in denominator. So, I was (almost) sure that all of that had to simplify a lot.

Comment: Very good insight. The coefficients are chosen carefully so that they will cancel out. If I chose different coefficients, I don't think the problem would be as trivial.

Comment: @Deepak. You are perfectly right ! I am sure that this is the way to build this kind of problem : start with the expansion of $\cos^nx$ as a function of multiple angles and ask the student to do the reverse ! Cheers :_)

Comment: Well, I had an inkling that something like this was going on because the coefficients looked like binomial coefficients (Pascal's triangle), but (unlike you), I didn't have the "intestinal fortitude" (i.e. guts) to actually attempt the expansion in case it went nowhere! :) Cheers.

Comment: @Deepak. Look at http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAngles.htm

Comment: That's wonderful! Thanks! :)

Comment: You are very welcome ! Try to remember the trick. Cheers :-)